# Javascript not returning the month from unix timestamp

Tags: javascript

I have a UNIX timestamp `1411866803` which is equivalent to `Sun, 28 Sep 2014 01:13:23 GMT`

I want to get the month from the timestamp according to local time of the user. I use the following function:

```
<script>
var date = new Date(1411866803);
var month = date.getMonth();
alert(month);
</script>
```

This should return `9` instead it returns `0`. Is there something wrong with the above syntax? Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript timestamps are expressed in milliseconds. Multiply by 1000:

```
var date = new Date(1411866803000);
var month = date.getMonth();
alert(month); // => 8
```

Also, months are 0-based, so September is `8`, not `9`.

Answer (score 2):

The Date object takes in milliseconds, whereas UNIX timestamps use seconds. You have to convert it over.

```js
var date = new Date(1411866803*1000);
var month = date.getMonth();
alert(month);
```

Answer (score 2):

The Date object takes as milisecond instead of seconds. So, just put three zeroes and you will be fine.

```
var date = new Date(1411866803000);
var month = date.getMonth();
alert(month);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I test your script in a console, I get this date to be:

```
var date = new Date(1411866803)
Date {Sat Jan 17 1970 20:11:06 GMT+1200 (NZST)}
```

And according to that page : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp

> The getMonth() method returns the month (from 0 to 11) for the specified date, according to local time.
>
> Note: January is 0, February is 1, and so on.